# Receive frame of ADC samples via SPI with discontinuous clock using DMA

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, dma

With stm32u5 as SPI master I'd like to use DMA to receive sample data from an external ADC ([LTC2512-24](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/251224fa.pdf)). The ADC has pretty tight timing requirements that SCK stop 740ns after the falling edge of the Data Ready Line (DRL) and stay quiet until the next DRL falling edge (when the next 24bit sample is ready in the ADC shift register)

I have this working by modifying a NUCLEO-u5 SPI-DMA Cube example (autonomous mode, triggering on DRL) but I get only one trigger on the first DRL and one sample read. Nothing afterwards.

Implementing an SPI ISR to setup the "next" DMA xfer, I can get a cycle of reads however this means waking every sample.  I would like to be able to sleep the device and wake only to process a frame of samples rather than each one individually so I can remain in sleep/stop mode longer.

I may not be understanding the reference manual but it seems this is impossible without having a continuous SCK between samples (at least using DMA and autonomous mode)

Do I have this right?

The MCU supports a RDY signal on SPI but this ADC doesn't provide it. I wonder if I could generate RDY from DRL using a one-pulse mode timer, then set my SPI receive to use a large TSIZE that gets paused automatically between samples on RDY=low. The reference manual isn't clear if SCK gets paused in this case.

I read about another technique where you use SPI in slave mode and generate the desired SCK pattern from stm32 using TIMs. Sounds complicated, but is this something I should explore?

Looking for some general guidance about the simplest way to go here as I'm pretty new with embedded programming.

Comment: Looks like a tricky problem. If the spi can do 24bit transfers, you’ll probably need a dma channel to write to the spi to start the transfer, and dma channel to read the result and a timer or two to trigger the conversion and trigger the dma. Will require careful reading of the ST user manual.

Comment: FWIW I haven't had any issue triggering the SPI directly with DRL, the issue seems to be re-triggering. I would assume I'd have the same problem if I could get DMA to somehow trigger SPI. I'm new at embedded programming and the reference manual is a head-scratcher but I'll keep at it.

Comment: I’ve not had recent experience with the stm32, so my advice is general. Unfortunately you’ll most likely have to read the manual a few times to get a feel for how it all works. The cubemx libraries abstract the operation and can obscure what they actually do. Your solution will probably end up being part cubemx and direct access. You chose a good project to cut your teeth on embedded! One technique you might find useful is the control the peripherals in the debugger - examine and modify the peripherals directly rather than change code and repeat.